# Create DCP with experience manager

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

For the news section on our website, we use DCP's. We have 1 news detail page where any news item can be displayed. This is fetched from the broker database by using a querystring parameter. I can read everywhere that experience manager works fine with dynamic content, and this is true as long as it's about editing this content. With the correct XPM tags, it works fine. However I can't seem to find a way to allow the creation of such components. I can either "Create and insert content" or "Insert content", but both will add the component to the page... I don't want that to happen. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

XPM is setup from a Page concept indeed, and therefore it is not possible to create content which you will not insert on a Page. This type of content is expected to be created in the CME.

The up side is, that you can easily reach the CME from the XPM interface, just select the slide out menu and proceeed to the Content Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality is lacking and it's not out of the box. But you could potentially write a GUI Extension to "Create Content Only" and not insert it on the page as a Component Presentation